# How to set up a lightweight ethereum node?

Tags: nodes

I would like to find out if it is possible to configure an ethereum node on ubuntu so that it does not store the entire history of the blockchain, but only the last couple of blocks. All I need is an analysis of incoming transactions, and as I understand it, just a couple of blocks are required to confirm them. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try prune the node on start up - https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/pruning

Bare in mind if data storage is a constraint for you there are other alternatives like Etherscan where you can set up your parameters and it will probably involve a lot less work on your side.